# Best way to add the following logic in spark pipeline?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-beam

[Brainstorm exercise] I have this business logic which is responsible for removing abusive text from the given text. The flow is

fetch data from elasticsearch for a `textId` -> for each text document identify spans of abusive text -> for each text document remove the abusive text span -> persist each text document back in elasticsearch.

I am formulating this pipeline in spark by

1. Fetch a PCollection of `textId` (bounded data set) from noSql database
2. Apply AbusiveTextRemoverTransform (it doesnt output any PCollection). The entire business logic is housed in this Transform.

But now it seems like that this spark pipeline has only 1 stage and it seems wrong. But lets say if I want to break the "identifying span" & "removing span" into two stages then that would mean transferring text (1-10MB) from one stage to another. [Question 1] Has that worked in your experience?

[Question 2] Having just one stage in Spark pipeline , is it a good way to leverage spark or sounds like an overkill? Arguably, i can create multiple threads to achieve the same.
What are your thoughts around it?

Comment: What is the SDK/runner combination that you are using? Beam Java SDK and SparkRunner?

Comment: yeah, Beam java sdk and spark runner.

Comment: A Spark job with a single stage it absolutely fine, what matters is not the number of stages but the degree of parallelism in your pipeline. And that heavily depends on the number of executors and the way you read from your database. A stage in Spark corresponds to the physical execution plan: In some cases it's beneficial to better distribute (shuffle) data (which increases the stages), but typically you want to keep the number of stages as low as possible. Also, splitting your transform into multiple ParDos won't add Spark stages, therefore costs are insignificant...

Comment: To get support it might be a good idea to rephrase the question and use Beam terminology only. The mix above makes it a bit hard to understand what you are trying to achieve.